# Android native fragment vs roboguice support v4 library fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, roboguice, android-support-library

i have an XML layout file, which is inflated by an Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>
<LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/content2"
      android:background="@color/lighter_gray"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment class="com.xyz.fragments.TabFragment"
          android:id="@+id/tabs"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_width="0px"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  />
<FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
  android:layout_weight="2"
  android:layout_width="0px"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The Activity is a subclass (not direct) of  FragmentActivity (from v4 library).

Now, in com.xyz.fragments.TabFragment, i have the following class declaration

```
....
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import roboguice.fragment.RoboListFragment;

public class TabFragment extends RoboListFragment {

.... 
....
```

when running, the app crashed, and the adb logcat shows the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.xyz/com.xyz.xxActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
```

so line #22 is exactly this line in xml layout

```
fragment class="com.xyz.fragments.TabFragment"
```

it is being red-underlined...and it says 
     TabFragment is not assignable to android.app.fragment

alright i get it, i am using a FragmentList from roboguice which is from support library v4, not same as android.app.fragment

so...what can i do? and i am assuimg this is the reason why app crashed.

full stack trace below

0-25 20:59:54.535: INFO/ApplicationPolicy(1903): isApplicationInstallationEnabled :  pkg com.xyz
10-25 20:59:55.455: INFO/PackageManager(1903): Removing non-system package:com.xyz
10-25 20:59:55.455: INFO/ActivityManager(1903): Force stopping package com.xyz uid=10017
10-25 20:59:55.610: INFO/PackageManager(1903): ICS_DEBUG scanPackageLI entered  com.xyz
10-25 20:59:55.610: INFO/PackageManager(1903): ICS_DEBUG checking for  com.xyz
10-25 20:59:55.615: INFO/PackageManager(1903): Running dexopt on: com.xyz
10-25 20:59:58.390: INFO/ActivityManager(1903): Force stopping package com.xyz uid=10017
10-25 20:59:59.305: DEBUG/PackageManager(1903): New package installed in /data/app/com.xyz-2.apk
10-25 20:59:59.705: INFO/ActivityManager(1903): Force stopping package com.xyz uid=10017
10-25 20:59:59.875: DEBUG/Launcher.LauncherModel(2152): --> package:com.xyz
10-25 21:00:00.050: INFO/SocialHub(6289): [UinboxReceiver] onReceive() >>   intent.getData() : com.xyz
10-25 21:00:00.345: DEBUG/Launcher.LauncherModel(2152): --> update package com.xyz
10-25 21:00:00.345: DEBUG/Launcher.LauncherModel(2152): --> package:com.xyz
10-25 21:00:00.640: INFO/DebugDb(2152): Update app info -1 com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.ApplicationInfo xyz -1 4 15 75|-1|-1|-1|-1|0 com.sec.android.app.twlauncher.ApplicationInfo@421323f0
10-25 21:00:01.675: INFO/ActivityManager(1903): START {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.xyz/.TabActivity} from pid 7524
10-25 21:00:01.775: INFO/ActivityManager(1903): Start proc com.xyz for activity com.xyz/.TabActivity: pid=7536 uid=10017 gids={3003}
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xyz/com.xyz.TabActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
        at com.xyz.TabActivity.onCreate(TabActivity.java:25)
10-25 21:00:24.225: INFO/ActivityManager(1903): Process com.xyz (pid 7536) has died.

Answer (score 1):

Use `name` not `class` like so:

```
<fragment android:name="com.cyz.fragments.TabFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_tab"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Make sure the activity the fragment is attached to extends `RoboFragmentActivity`

Make sure you override the onCreateView in your fragment

```
public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

Also make sure you call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in your Activity's `onCreate()` before you try to do anything else.

Comment: thanks that removed the red underline, but same error occurs, the app crashes with the same msg as before, not able to inflate

Comment: can you add the whole stack trace?

Comment: just updated my question to include full stack trace after ur changes.  please note that the error is in the layout that is assigned to the activity, which contains a fragment.  also TabFragment is a fragmentList

Comment: Is your activity extending `RoboFragmentActivity`?

Comment: thanks james for debugging, as mentioned in my question, it is extending FragmentActivity from v4 library.  i just changed FragmentActivity to RoboFragmentActivity, app still crahses with the same error msg

Comment: I don't know why I didn't notice before but your XML can only have one root element.  Right now you have two: A `RelativeLayout` that is not doing anything and a `LinearLayout`.  Try getting rid of the RelativeLayout, or if you need it put the LinearLayout inside it.

Comment: thanks for looking at it again James, i don't think it is the issue. i think it has to do with roboguice, becuase as long as i don't use roboguice's fragment, then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain but I am calling the super class in all my fragments and that works for me.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
}
```

Check if that works.